# ExtendedRenderKitService not applying javascript scrollTop in modeless popup dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-adf, scrolltop

I have a method invoked from the *actionListener* of an *af:commandLink*:

```
public static void invokeFunction(String function) {
    ExtendedRenderKitService service =
        Service.getRenderKitService(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
            ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
    String invokeFn =  function;
    service.addScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), invokeFn);        
}
```

that invokes the following j/s function:

```
function scrollTopInit(posvals) {
    var list = posvals.split(",");
    window.console && console.log("found # ul " +  $(".af_selectManyListbox_options").length);
    $(".af_selectManyListbox_options").each ( function( i, el ) {
        window.console && console.log("ul has " + $(el).children().length);
        var pos = list[ i ];
        if (pos) {
            window.console && console.log("i = " + i + " pos = " + pos);
            $(el).scrollTop(pos);
        }
    });
}
```

with the intention of positioning the ordered lists created by af:selectManyListbox so that the
uppermost checked value will show at the top. All logging and debugging through firebug indicates
that this is working yet all lists remain exactly as they are.

Yet, if I try the following expression in the firebug console window, it moves all the ordered
lists as desired:

```
$(".af_selectManyListbox_options").each(function(i,el){if(i==0){console.log(i);   $(el).scrollTop(100);}});
```

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 without issue for other bean driven j/s client-side manipulation through the ExtendedRenderKitService such as perfect scrollbar without issue.

What is the problem with scrollTop that is blocking this effort?

NB: invoking same function from the popupfetchlistener of the popup (invoked from the commandLink) makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution as I had just determined is simply ensuring that all of the actions I have
described above occur *AFTER* the popup is rendered for unless the popup is visible, the
scrollTop will always return 0 regardless of what you attempt to set it to.

How to ensure this occurs after popup rendered? Simple. In the popup tag ensure that you
have both a clientlistener and a serverlistener. Have the method invoked by the
clientlistener fire a custom event that invokes the serverlistener which then invokes the
backend to call the extendedrenderkit to tweak the scrolTop via jQuery.

so in fragment with popup:

```
  <af:serverListener type="scrollPosEvent" method="#{viewScope.configBean.scrollTopSet}"/>               
  <af:clientListener method="settingsClick" type="popupOpened" />               
</af:popup>
```

so settingsClick fires the scrollPosEvent():

```
settingsClick = function(event) {
  var tab = event.getSource();
  AdfCustomEvent.queue(tab, "scrollPosEvent");
}
```

which customevent fires the serverlistener above which then fires the scrollTopSet() method

```
public void scrollTopSet(ClientEvent clientEvent) {
  clientEvent.getComponent();
  SmartViewUtils.invokeFunction("scrollTopInit('" + scrollParms + "');"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you added the following code

```
function scrollTopInit(posvals) {
var list = posvals.split(",");
window.console && console.log("found # ul " +  $(".af_selectManyListbox_options").length);
$(".af_selectManyListbox_options").each ( function( i, el ) {
    window.console && console.log("ul has " + $(el).children().length);
    var pos = list[ i ];
    if (pos) {
        window.console && console.log("i = " + i + " pos = " + pos);
        $(el).scrollTop(pos);
    }
});
```

}

as **function** parameter, that means you created a function, not calling it, you should call it afterwards by calling

```
scrollTopInit(...)
```

Comment: Yes, I am indeed invoking the scrollTopInit() function with applicable string paramaeters from the backend bean using the invokeFunction() method. That is not the problem.